# modeltranslation NotRegistered

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

столкнулся с такой проблемой, установил `modeltranslation` и пытаюсь сделать сайт на двух языках, файл settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'modeltranslation',
    'spica.apps.SpicaConfig',
    'events.apps.EventsConfig',
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('Russia')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
```

Файл models.py:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tags = models.CharField(verbose_name='Теги', max_length=50)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Файл translations.py:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import (
    translator,
    TranslationOptions
)
from events.models import (
    Tags,
    Events
)

class TagsTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('tags',)

translator.register(Tags, TagsTranslationOptions)
```

Тут все норм, миграции проходят, поля видны в админке и в самой базе, но при добавлении `from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin` в файле admin.py появляется ошибка, admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from events.models import Tags, Events
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin

class TagsAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Tags, TagsAdmin)
```

Пишет что модель tags не зарегистрирован для перевода. `modeltranslation.translator.NotRegistered: The model "Tags" is not registered for translation`. Так же при наследовании класса с `admin.ModelAdmin` все нормально.